# How to I resize an item in a QListWidget upon the resize of the window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using a QStyledItemDelegate to change the appearance of the `QListWidgetItems` in my `QItemWidget`. I want to change the height of the items depending on the size of the text. I am using `sizeHint()` which works fine on the initial creation. The problem is when the window resizes, the text reformats and leaves empty spaces. How do I resize the items to remove the empty space?

[image: On initial]

[image: After resizing]

Comment: Are you aware of [`QListView::resizeMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#resizeMode-prop)? (`QListWidget` is derived from `QListView`.) _By default, this property is set to [Fixed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#ResizeMode-enum)._ Does it help if you set [Adjust](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#ResizeMode-enum) instead?

Comment: This works. I was not aware of this property. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setResizeMode` to `QListView::Adjust` instead of `QListView::Fixed`.